# How do I install the NUnit plugin in Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-2013

I am not able to run the unit tests in Visual Studio 2013 like I used to be able to run it from the Visual Studio window itself in Visual Studio 2010. I am not able to find anything in NuGet Package Manager or on the web.

Comment: Note there is an NUnit test runner add-in which you download via *Tools|Extensions and Updates* - the problem which as you've discovered this doesn't work in Express editions]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  The Express SKUs of Visual Studio do not support plugins / extensions.

Comment: That's what i revealed after i did my research. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: _"do not support plugins / extensions"_ - That's not entirely correct.  Express 2013 editions do not support **3rd party** extensions.  [Tell me more](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Try to use **NUnit TestAdapter including NUnit**. You will find it searching for NUnit in the **Manage NuGet Packages** window.

I have tested it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is in blog post *[How to invoke NUnit from Visual studio express and execute automation tests](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-execute-invoke-nunit-from-visual.html)*.

Comment: I come from the future and seek a workaround. This answer is still a link-only one.

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_