# Getting F# tests to be detected by Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nunit, visual-studio-2013

I've defined the following F# file:

```
module MyFsTest

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<Test>]
let ``1 + 1 = 2``() = Assert.AreEqual(2, 1+1)
```

yet when I try to run them either through "Test Explorer" or "Right Click + Run Tests" a build is done yet no tests are detected/run:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0320018) ==========
```

After googling a bit I've found my approach seems to resemble the steps taken @ http://davesquared.net/2013/03/hello-world-testing-in-fsharp.html, so I was wondering if there's something else I might be missing?

Comment: Can you rule in/out whether you have a NUnit runner plugin for VS (and/or its version)? Do C# test get discovered / run (I doubt ti as there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong) ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink: That was it. I didn't have a NUnit plugin installed. But looking at the VS Gallery, there seems to be no version supporting VS2013 yet :(.

Comment: It seems there is no way to get it to work with an express edition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907842/how-to-install-nunit-plugin-in-visual-studio-2013-express

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use NUnit tests with the built-in Visual Studio test runner, you'd need to install the [NUnit test adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d). This is available for Visual Studio 2013, but I believe it is not possible to install it as an extension to the Express edition.

However, the Express edition includes support for the Microsoft [Visual Studio testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework), which is supported by the built-in test runner. The usage should be pretty similar to NUnit - you'll just need different namespaces.

Comment: Why does 'Ctrl + U + R' in the test method not work? I have Resharper installed and when I use the short-cut within the method Resharper simply says "No tests found in the file". However if I go to the test project and right click choosing Run Tests, the tests will be run, namely Ctrl + U + R works on the test project but not the test file. In C# it works on both. Is this a Resharper plugin problem?

Comment: You might need a [newer version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter) of the NUnit Test Adapter.